# Undefined index: expiry_date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the user the expiry date from created_at in laravel I'm using carbon but when I submit the form it gives this message "Undefined index: expiry_date** why??? How I calculate 1-day expiry date from the current date(create_at)

**my register controller  code is**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

 use App\User;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
 use Carbon\Carbon;

 class RegisterController extends Controller
{
use RegistersUsers;


protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}


protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'phone' => ['required', 'string'],
        'country' => ['required', 'string'],
        'state' => ['required', 'string'],
        'purpose' => ['required', 'string'],
        'package' => ['required', 'string'],
        'months' => ['required', 'string'],
        'quantity' => ['required', 'string'],
        'amount' => ['required', 'string'],
    ]);
}


protected function create(array $data)
{

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'country' => $data['country'],
        'state' => $data['state'],
        'purpose' => $data['purpose'],
        'expiry_date' => Carbon::now()->addHours($data['expiry_date']),  

        //'package' => $data['package'],
       // 'months' => $data['months'],
        //'quantity' => $data['quantity'],
        //'amount' => $data['amount'],
    ]);
}
}
```

please help me. to solve this and how I calculate user expiry from the current date for one data

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems $data['expiry_date'] is not set

Comment: What do you have in `$data['expiry_date']`? Do `dd($data['expiry_data'])` before return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `expiry_date` from `request()`, because it's not defined in `Validator`.

You need to add `expiry_date` :

#### Solution #1

```php
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name'        => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'email'       => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    'password'    => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    'phone'       => ['required', 'string'],
    'country'     => ['required', 'string'],
    'state'       => ['required', 'string'],
    'purpose'     => ['required', 'string'],
    'package'     => ['required', 'string'],
    'months'      => ['required', 'string'],
    'quantity'    => ['required', 'string'],
    'amount'      => ['required', 'string'],
    'expire_date' => ['YOUR RULES'],         // <----------
]);
```

#### Solution #2

Or if you want to define `expire_date` 1-day expiry from `now()`, you should :

```php
return User::create([
    'name'        => $data['name'],
    'email'       => $data['email'],
    'password'    => Hash::make($data['password']),
    'phone'       => $data['phone'],
    'country'     => $data['country'],
    'state'       => $data['state'],
    'purpose'     => $data['purpose'],
    'expiry_date' => Carbon::now()->addDay(),
]);
```

Comment: Now I get this error when click a call log menu "Trying to get property 'expiry_date' of non-object"...Please see my attached image

Comment: @AyushSrivastava can you `dd($callog)`?

Comment: @AyushSrivastava glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Seems you dont have the expiry_date in your request. So first try to print the value of expiry_date.

If it doesn't exist then check your request.

You can also use current date such as

```
'expiry_date' => Carbon\Carbon::now()
```

Or in PHP you can do it like

```
'expiry_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```